# Making a simple PHP script process text in a pipe

Tags: text-processing, scripting

Last week I wanted to convert some simplified Chinese characters into traditional ones. I found a [deceptively nice looking shell one-liner](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8071/a-simple-interactive-tool-to-convert-simplified-chinese-typed-by-pinyin-to-traditional-chinese-), which today I found out was 20% error prone.

So I did some research. The mediawiki codebase contains conversion tables that take the idiosyncratic nature of simplified orthography into account, and someone already wrote a nice helper library full of dummy classes and functions, called mediawiki-zhconverter. So it appeared I could have my one-liner, which I would prefer looked something like this, stconvert being the name of the script I'm writing:

```
$cat simplifiedstory | stconvert > traditionalstory
```

However, mediawiki is entirely PHP, and I have never written any PHP, so I don't know how it deals with shell variables. As you can see below, simply putting '$argv' where a string would go does not achieve my goal.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

define("MEDIAWIKI_PATH", "/home/a1/mediawiki-1.13.0/");
require_once "mediawiki-zhconverter.inc.php";
echo MediaWikiZhConverter::convert($argv, "zh-tw") , ",";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it.  $argv is an array, similar to perl.  $argv[0] is the script itself, like $0 in shell, or $ARGV[0] in perl.  $argv[1] would be the first argument passed to the script, but your usage would probably change since you can do the cat in your php script.  Assuming your php script is `stconvert`, usage would now be `stconvert simplifiedstory > traditionalstory`.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

define("MEDIAWIKI_PATH", "/home/a1/mediawiki-1.13.0/");
require_once "mediawiki-zhconverter.inc.php";

$text = shell_exec("cat $argv[1]");
echo MediaWikiZhConverter::convert($text, "zh-tw") , ",";

?>
```

Comment: it works beautifully. i guess i didn't need that extra comma at the end of the echo...

Comment: i'm glad to hear that.

Comment: I am the developer of mediawiki-zhconverter, I am also glad that you find my code useful :)

Comment: As a general note, for those looking for a way to use stdin and stdout: PHP has predefined streams and file descriptors you can use. For example: `echo str_replace('foo', 'bar', file_get_contents('php://stdin');` would replace all `foo` with `bar` in the piped input. If you want a file handle, use `STDIN`. For example, when piping a CSV file: `while (($record = fgetcsv(STDIN))) { print_r($record); }`.